# Stuck at Whitescreen after building Ionic React android app

Tags: android, reactjs, android-studio, ionic-framework

`ionic run android -l --external` with this I got to test the app on phone with hot reloading, but when I try to build it on studio it just shows a blank white screen after the capacitor logo.

I am just testing out ionic, just got the tabs template going on to test it out.

here's how I build the apk.
`ionic run android` -> then on android studio -> build apk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm getting a similar problem, using WSL and the Windows Android Studio:

On WSL:

```
ionic start photo-gallery tabs --type=react --capacitor 
cd photo-gallery/ 
ionic integrations enable capacitor
npx cap init photo-app com.mike.atkinson 

mkdir www
-- create a www/index.html file
npx cap add android 
ionic serve                  #check everything runs OK in a browser then ^C
#line below stops a warning in the Windows Android Studio when the App is run.
mkdir node_modules/@capacitor/android/capacitor/build/intermediates/check_manifest_result/debug/checkDebugManifest/out
```

On Windows:

```
    Run Android Studio
    Select photo-app 
    build it
    Create an Android Virtual Machine - using Pixel XL with Android 10
    Select it
    Run photo-app                                                <-- just a blank screen
    Connect phone (Umidigi A3S  running Android 10)
    Select phone 
    Run photo-app                     <-- just shows the splash screen then a blank screen
```

As I am new to Android, it is probably something I'm doing wrong, but as this is an example React app I can't figure out what.

It turns out I made two simple errors:

1. In capacitor.config.json the webDir should be set to "build"
2. Ionic serve only does the build for the web service, to build for the android target you need to do:

```
npm run build
```

then run the Android Studio on the Windows side.

Comment: Yeah, it was the webDir problem for me too as well, should be "build" I remember changing it the first run to public coz it won't let me run it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using angular, but ran into the same situation. For me it was my (Windows) firewall blocking port 8100.

So I added the Inbound rule to allow TCP traffic on port 8100 (Private and Domain, NOT public).

Next problem was that my WiFi was, by default, set to a public WiFi... So I corrected this and it all worked!